# Tomcat JNDIRealm authenticate and ignore all roles

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ldap, authorization, jndi

Tomcat container use LDAP to authenticate user

I am trying to replace Tomcat's inMemory user database with LDAP authentication. making changes in conf/server.xml

When user login popus up i want to compare user credentials against ldap.

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
 connectionName="abcusername" 
 connectionPassword="mypassword" 
 connectionURL="ldap://ada.cab.ast.com:389" 
 debug="10" userBase="DC=cab,DC=ast,DC=com" 
 userSearch="(cn={0})" 
 userSubtree="true"/>
```

My web.xml, if user is authenticated all no role restriction

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTML Manager interface (for humans)</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

When i provide correct username and password i see in following log that user is authenticated but failed authorization i guess and failed.
any help is appreciated.

```
AuthenticatorBase.register Authenticated 'fkhan002c' with type 'BASIC'
AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling accessControl()
hasResourcePermission   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[fkhan002c()]
AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Failed accessControl() test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem

Web-resource-collection is for java resources as i was trying to autherize static content as you can see following i also  needed  for static contents.

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure contents</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Secure content</realm-name>
    </login-config>


<security-role>
       <description>
           This logical role includes all administrative users
       </description>
       <role-name>*</role-name>
   </security-role>
```